# VBA to delete unused named ranges in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have several workbooks that contain 3,500+ named ranges, most of which are not used.  To clean up the mess, I would like to run a macro that deletes any unused names.

The following macro seems to work, but it takes about half an hour to run.  I actually turned on the status bar so I could be sure it was still progressing.

I would like to get advice on how to accomplish this task more efficiently.

```
Sub DeleteUnusedNames()
'PURPOSE:   Delete named ranges that are not used in formulas in the active workbook

    Dim xWB As Workbook:    Set xWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim xWS As Worksheet
    Dim xNameCount As Long  'Count of all named ranges
    Dim xCount As Long      'Count of current range - used to track progress
    Dim xFound As Long      'Count of times a named range was used in a formula - moves on to next code when > 0
    Dim xDeletedCount As Long
    Dim xName As Name

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    On Error Resume Next

    xNameCount = xWB.Names.count

    For Each xName In xWB.Names
        If xName.Name Like "*Print_*" Then  'Skip Print Areas and Print Titles
        Else
            xFound = 0
            xCount = xCount + 1
            Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & xCount & " of " & xNameCount & " (" & Format(xCount / xNameCount, "0%") & ")"

            For Each xWS In xWB.Worksheets
                If xWS.Name Like "Workbook Properties" Then 'Don't search the Workbook Properties tab for Names (if this tab exists, it will not have any used names)
                Else
                    xFound = xFound + xWS.UsedRange.Find(What:=xName.Name, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False).count
                    If xFound > 0 Then Exit For   'Name was found. Stop looking.
                End If
            Next xWS

            If xFound = 0 Then  'Name was not found in a formula on any of the worksheets
                xName.Delete
                xDeletedCount = xDeletedCount + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next xName

    If xMsg = "" Then
        MsgBox "No unused names were found in the workbook", , "No named ranges were deleted"
    Else
        MsgBox xDeletedCount & " names were deleted", , "Unused named ranges were deleted"
    End If

    Application.StatusBar = False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: I think the first thing i would try would be to search those specific name ranges, instead of `UsedRange` ... that should limit drastically the search. Also even as it is, should probably just search for 1 occurence, rather than a total count... given you want to exit the loop as soon you have more than 0.

Comment: @DarXyde But, that won't pick up if Named Range "SomeRange" (`Sheet1!A1:C3`) is used in a cell that isn't in any Named Ranges (e.g. `Sheet3!AZ65534`) - and it *does* currently use `Exit For` as soon as `xFound > 0`

Comment: I see, you are right... my bad. See the second part of my comment... and the next thing i can suggest is using arrays and loop over the arrays instead... though not completely sure how to easily allocate the formulas to the array directly, not the values... `arr = Range("XYZ").Formula` .. let me try to put this together as an answer, see if it helps.

Comment: @DarXyde I thought about using arrays, but wasn't sure how to put the named ranges into the array without looping through them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented above, please give this a try.

Is putting all the formulas in arrays rather than named ranges.

```vb
Sub DeleteUnusedNames()
'PURPOSE:   Delete named ranges that are not used in formulas in the active workbook

    Dim xWB As Workbook:    Set xWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim xWS As Worksheet
    Dim xNameCount As Long  'Count of all named ranges
    Dim xCount As Long      'Count of current range - used to track progress
    Dim xFound As Long      'Count of times a named range was used in a formula - moves on to next code when > 0
    Dim xDeletedCount As Long
    Dim xName As Name
    Dim arrData As Variant  'an array to hold all formulas
    Dim R As Long, C As Long    'rows/columns

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    On Error Resume Next

    xNameCount = xWB.Names.Count

    For Each xName In xWB.Names
        If xName.Name Like "*Print_*" Then  'Skip Print Areas and Print Titles
        Else
            xFound = 0
            xCount = xCount + 1
            Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & xCount & " of " & xNameCount & " (" & Format(xCount / xNameCount, "0%") & ")"

            For Each xWS In xWB.Worksheets
                If xWS.Name Like "Workbook Properties" Then 'Don't search the Workbook Properties tab for Names (if this tab exists, it will not have any used names)
                Else
                    arrData = xWS.UsedRange.Formula

                    For R = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
                        For C = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
                            If InStr(1, arrData(R, C), xName.Name) > 0 Then
                                xFound = 1
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next C
                        If xFound > 0 Then Exit For
                    Next R
                End If
            Next xWS

            If xFound = 0 Then  'Name was not found in a formula on any of the worksheets
                xName.Delete
                xDeletedCount = xDeletedCount + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next xName

    If xMsg = "" Then
        MsgBox "No unused names were found in the workbook", , "No named ranges were deleted"
    Else
        MsgBox xDeletedCount & " names were deleted", , "Unused named ranges were deleted"
    End If

    Application.StatusBar = False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Could replace that loop with the below, should hold all data (... well, hopefully). If all the usedranges load successfully, then it should be a breeze to loop through everything.

```vb
    Dim Z As Long
    Dim arrWholeData() As Variant: ReDim arrWholeData(xWB.Worksheets.Count)

    For Z = 1 To xWB.Worksheets.Count
        arrWholeData(Z) = xWB.Worksheets(Z).UsedRange.Formula
    Next Z

    For Each xName In xWB.Names
        If xName.Name Like "*Print_*" Then  'Skip Print Areas and Print Titles
        Else
            xFound = 0
            xCount = xCount + 1
            Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & xCount & " of " & xNameCount & " (" & Format(xCount / xNameCount, "0%") & ")"

            For Z = 1 To xWB.Worksheets.Count
                For R = LBound(arrWholeData(Z)) To UBound(arrWholeData(Z))
                    For C = LBound(arrWholeData(Z), 2) To UBound(arrWholeData(Z), 2)
                        If InStr(1, arrWholeData(Z)(R, C), xName.Name) > 0 Then
                            xFound = 1
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next C
                    If xFound > 0 Then Exit For
                Next R
                If xFound > 0 Then Exit For
            Next Z

            If xFound = 0 Then  'Name was not found in a formula on any of the worksheets
                xName.Delete
                xDeletedCount = xDeletedCount + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next xName
```

**EDIT:** added an alternative.

***EDIT: FINAL COMPLETE CODE:***

```
Sub DeleteUnusedNames()
'PURPOSE:   Delete named ranges that are not used in formulas in the active workbook

    Dim startTime As Single, endTime As Single
    startTime = Timer

    Dim xWB As Workbook:    Set xWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim xNameCount As Long: xNameCount = xWB.Names.count
    Dim xCount As Long      'Count of current range - used to track progress
    Dim xFound As Long      'Count of times a named range was used in a formula - moves on to next code when > 0
    Dim xDeleted As Long    'Count of deleted named ranges
    Dim xArrWholeData() As Variant: ReDim xArrWholeData(xWB.Worksheets.count)
    Dim xRow As Long        'Row number
    Dim xCol As Long        'Column number
    Dim xName As Name       'Used for looping through names
    Dim xWSNum As Long      'Used for looping through worksheets
    Dim xNName As String    'Name of current named range in the loop - used for comparing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    On Error Resume Next

    For xWSNum = 1 To xWB.Worksheets.count
        xArrWholeData(xWSNum) = xWB.Worksheets(xWSNum).UsedRange.Formula
    Next xWSNum

    For Each xName In xWB.Names
        xNName = xName.Name
        xCount = xCount + 1

        If xCount Mod 50 = 0 Then
            endTime = Timer
            Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & xCount & " of " & xNameCount & " (" & Format(xCount / xNameCount, "0%") & ")   " & (endTime - startTime) & " seconds have passed"
        End If

        If xNName Like "*Print_*" Then   'Skip Print Areas and Print Titles
        Else
            xFound = 0

            For xWSNum = 1 To xWB.Worksheets.count
                If xWB.Worksheets(xWSNum).Name Like "Workbook Properties" Then   'Skip the Workbook Properties worksheet
                Else
                    For xRow = LBound(xArrWholeData(xWSNum)) To UBound(xArrWholeData(xWSNum))
                        For xCol = LBound(xArrWholeData(xWSNum), 2) To UBound(xArrWholeData(xWSNum), 2)
                            If InStr(1, xArrWholeData(xWSNum)(xRow, xCol), xNName) > 0 Then
                                xFound = 1  'Name was found
                                GoTo NextName  'Stop looking for this name and go to the next name
                            End If
                        Next xCol
                    Next xRow
                End If
            Next xWSNum

            If xFound = 0 Then  'Name was not found in a formula on any of the worksheets
                xDeleted = xDeleted + 1
                xName.Delete
            End If
        End If

NextName:
    Next xName

    endTime = Timer
    Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & xCount & " of " & xNameCount & " (" & Format(xCount / xNameCount, "0%") & ")   " & (endTime - startTime) & " seconds have passed"

    If xDeleted = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No unused names were found in the workbook", , "No named ranges were deleted"
    Else
        MsgBox xDeleted & " names were deleted:", , "Unused named ranges were deleted"  'Removed & vbCr & xMsg before the first comma
    End If

    Application.StatusBar = False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: I thought since there are more names than worksheets it would be best to loop through the names first (once), and the worksheets second (multiple times).  Perhaps I wasn't thinking that through very well, since I am actually looking at every cell in the used range of each worksheet every time I'm looping.  I'll give that idea a try.

Comment: The main idea is to interact with the workbook as little as possible, and with `for each cell in usedrange` you are interacting way to much. Unfortunately by looping `for each name`, it means reading the data from all sheets 3,500+ times, so even with the above is not going to be instant, though should be much faster than 35minutes. As an alternative idea, you could preallocate to a larger array all the usedranges, and then loop over that instead (and then shouldn't matter the order of the loops i guess).

Comment: I've added an alternative loop that should hold all the usedranges in a larger array. Might depend on the number of the sheets/size of your data, but please feel free to experiment... hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe I'm using it wrong, but the first code was slower than my original.  The second code was also very slow, and didn't work.

Comment: Any chance is one of these workbooks shareable? doubtfully, but lazy to create a sample for testing purposes.

Comment: Not shareable... sorry, I know that makes it harder to help.

Comment: Approx how many sheets per workbook? And approx how many rows/columns ?

Comment: By the way, please note that i`ve updated the second loop earlier... you might have tried the broken one? (was experimenting something...). Please see the updated answer and give it another shot?

Comment: Yes, I was using the broken second loop.  The updated one runs very fast (impressive!) but isn't finding any named ranges to delete, so still isn't working.

Comment: In the If InStr line you used xWB.Names(X).Name ... where does X come from?  Should this be xWB.Names(Z).Name?

Comment: should be just `xName.Name` ... still part of the broken one lol. Updated the answer accordingly... sorry about it.

Comment: Genius!  It took 12.27344 seconds to run through 3,704 named ranges and delete the unused ones.  At the end I got the message box telling me that there were no unused names found in the workbook, so I'll have to tweak something, but the code totally works!  Thank you!! :-)

Comment: Oh... wait ... it deleted ALL the names (except Print Areas and Print Titles) in that workbook.  Not quite what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad it worked. I guess just change `If xMsg = "" Then` to `If xDeletedCount = 0 Then` should do the trick. I haven't checked that lel. OW! let's revisit that, though we are on the right track probably.

Comment: Ok, i think i've found the problem.. missed to exit one more loop if found. see updated or add this after R loop `If xFound > 0 Then Exit For`

Comment: Though that would only make it exit when `xFound > 0` and there is nothing within the inner loops to make `xFound  = 0` ... so not sure why it would delete all ? I`ve just tested this on a sizeable set, and seems to work as intended, exit earlier or not.

Comment: DarXyde, your code worked perfectly.  In the line of code I added to skip over the Workbook Properties worksheet I had messed up and used Worksheet instead of Worksheets, which caused the code to skip the whole loop.  No wonder it was so fast!  :-)  The final code still runs pretty quickly, taking a little over 3 minutes to run through each workbook.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Oh... glad it worked (again) :) . It was working for me with the sample i did, but when i tried to ramp it up to million rows over 15 sheets, 30 columns each (about 180mb workbook), excel just shutdown with no warning and restart... so i guess it will have certain limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative could be to check if the name range has any dependents :

```
Function HasDependents(r As Range)
    r.ShowDependents
    HasDependents = r.Address(, , , 1) <> r.NavigateArrow(0, 1).Address(, , , 1)
    r.ShowDependents 1
End Function
```

Sample use :

```
For Each xName In xWB.Names
    If Not HasDependents(xName.RefersToRange) Then xName.Delete
Next
```

Technically, this does not check if the name is used, but only if the range the name refers to is used (assuming all names refer to range). 
To go through the dependents and check if their formulas contain the name, this sample can be modified :
https://excelhelphq.com/how-to-find-all-dependent-cells-outside-of-worksheet-and-workbook-in-excel-vba/

Comment: Interesting approach, and I appreciate this.  I do have some defined names that are constants and don't actually refer to ranges, so this won't work for my situation.