# VBA code for deleting named ranges not refrenced in active workbook

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I want names all named ranges in my Excel file to be gone except those which refer to the current active workbook but my code does not do a proper job.

```
Sub deletenamesnotlocal()

Dim n As Name
Dim i As Worksheet


For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
For Each i In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

If n.RefersTo = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i) Then
Next i

Else: n.Delete

Next n


End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA to delete unused named ranges in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56294430/vba-to-delete-unused-named-ranges-in-excel)

Comment: Maybe provide a few example of the types of names you want to remove.

Comment: @PeterT I just tried out the code, very heavy and basically I think it doesn't resolve the issue in the end cause the code is focused on deleting names which are unused, whereby I want to delete names which are not referenced to my active workbook.

Comment: @TimWilliams Basically the issue is that most of the files in my company are loaded with useless names which weigh the file down. For example I received an excel file from one of my colleagues which was ~6MB but when I deleted all the names included the file size reduced to ~100KB. These names are referenced to god knows every where.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't help me understand exactly what type(s) of names need to be deleted.  A few concrete examples might be useful.

Comment: @TimWilliams These are named ranges, which are not refrenced to my file. Their scope might be worksheet or workbook, their result might be #REF or other values or ranges or even to files which do not make sense at all. I keep track of the names in Name Manager menu. I manage to delete these names through one-by-one inspection becuase my defined names lie between them. Please tell me if you needed more details.

Comment: Remove broken Names - https://www.teachexcel.com/free-excel-macros/m-18,delete-broken-ranges.html

Comment: @TimWilliams I acutally had come across to such a code, but this only deletes names running into #REF but I have numerous names which return a TRUE/FALSE value, containing a year digit or such things which technically are not broken, but also redundant. Major headaches are with ones which refrence a directory adress on a shared drive which does not exist and takes a lot of time to load and save the file.